# Given a set of PK in a Java Set, how to select all rows with PK in the set

Tags: mysql, jpa, select, set, entitymanager

I have a set of primary keys in a Java Set (of member ID). How can I pull all the membership records from the membership table whose primary key is in the set? JPA code sample with EntityManager would really helpful as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set<> pks...
String s = "SELECT m FROM Membership m WHERE m.id IN :ids";
TypedQuery<Membership> q = em.createQuery(s,Membership.class);

q.setParameter("ids",pks);
List<Membrship> result = q.getResultList()
```

Comment: Does this really work? The IN clause doesn't take a single parameter, it takes a comma-separated list, and providing a single collection value to substitute doesn't work in my exoerience, at least via JDBC.

Comment: it does. it is not sql it is jpql

Comment: Thanks folks. The code sample does work on my end here.